# Why is a signing config required for custom build type, but not for `release`?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-keystore, android-build-type

I have a custom build type `beta` defined like so:

```
buildTypes {                                                                                       

    debug {                                                                                        
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"                                                               
        testCoverageEnabled = false                                                                
    }                                                                                              

    release {                                                                                      
        minifyEnabled true                                                                         
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }                                                                                              

    beta {                                                                                         
        initWith release                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                              
}
```

Given that `beta` is using `initWith release`, one would expect beta to have all the properties of `release`. However, when attempting to run `beta`, Android Studio will show the following error

> "The APK for your current selected variant is not signed..."

Creating a signing configuration in the project settings, selecting it, and hitting "Apply" does not seem to work. Instead, a signing configuration has to be manually written:

```
signingConfigs {
    beta {
        storeFile file(‘…’)
        storePassword ‘…’
        keyAlias = ‘…’
        keyPassword ‘…’
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why does the signing config have to be manually written in the build script?
2. Why does the `release` build type not require an explicit signing config until you go to actually generate a signed APK?
3. Given that `beta` is supposed to be exactly like `release` via `initWith release`, why is the behavior different as shown above?